# Join 3 Different tables based on Type of post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables

posts (contain every posts type)

```
ID | type | PostID | timestamp
1  | 1    | 1      | 1378561301
2  | 2    | 1      | 1378561302
3  | 1    | 2      | 1378561303
4  | 2    | 2      | 1378561304
```

posts_messages

```
ID | message
1  | CAT
2  | RAT
```

posts_photos

```
ID | photo      | caption
1  | ant.jpg    | Ant
2  | orange.jpg | Orange
```

And I'd like to get the result like this

Result:

```
ID | Type | PostID     | timestamp  | message   | photo      | caption
1  | 1    | 1          | 1378561301 | CAT       | null       | null
2  | 2    | 1          | 1378561302 | null      | ant.jpg    | Ant
3  | 1    | 2          | 1378561303 | RAT       | null       | null
4  | 2    | 2          | 1378561304 | null      | orange.jpg | Orange
```

What i've tried is UNION but it's not complete. Any suggestion/alternative query ?

Comment: so ID in posts_messages and posts_photos are the one from posts ID ?

Comment: sqlfiddle or your query is needed.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen query is needed

Comment: What you probably need is a pair of LEFT JOINs. However, not a clue how you chose which output rows have columns from posts_messages and which have them from posts_photos

Comment: I don't get it. How are the tables linked? Table Post has an id and a post id? What else is the id of post when not a post id? Why is message 1 linked to post 1 and not to any other? I don't see what links a message (or a photo for that matter) to a post record.

Comment: Got It! type 1 means messages & type 2 means images. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this I think:-

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Type, a.PostID, a.timestamp, b.message, c.photo, c.caption
FROM posts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_messages b
ON a.PostID = b.ID AND a.type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_photosposts_photos c
ON a.PostID = c.ID AND a.type = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query -

```
select p.ID,p.Type,p.PostID,p.timestamp ,pm.message ,pp.photo,pp.caption
from posts p
left join posts_messages pm on pm.ID = p.ID
left join posts_photos pp on pp.ID = p.ID
```

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I did not get what u mean. Its one to many relation. And using left join i can get data in each row.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cab3a/5) which resultset  user asked for

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid u are right... So I asked him about "so ID in posts_messages and posts_photos are the one from posts ID" I should have been more clear on this "posts ID" I meant ID col of that table :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
select p.ID,p.Type,p.PostID,p.timestamp ,pm.message ,pp.photo,pp.caption
from posts p
left join posts_messages pm on pm.ID = p.ID
    and p.type = 1
left join posts_photos pp on pp.ID = p.ID
    and p.type = 2
```